# queries related to views.py file in django cms

Tags: python, linux, django-views, ubuntu-10.04, django-urls

This is my views.py file code(which is present in my app 'search' in django):

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

from dango.http import HttpResponse
from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list
from search.models Keywords

def front_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        str1 = request.POST['word']
        fo = open("xml.txt","r")

        for i in range(count.__len__()):

            file = fo.readline()
            file = file.rstrip('\n')
            find_root_tags(file,str1,i)

            list.append((file,count[i]))

        sorting_list(list)

        for name, count in list:
            s = Keywords(file_name=name,frequency_count=count)
            s.save()

            fo.close()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/results/')

    else :
        str1 = ''
        list = []
        template = loader.get_tamplate('search/search.html')
        response = template.render()
        return HttpResponse(response)


def results(request):

    list1 = Keywords.objects.all()
    t = loader.get_template('search/results.html')
    c = Context({'list1':list1,
    })

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

1)I wanted to know since I'm importing 'skey' file in views.py, so do I need to keep this 'skey.py', 'xml.txt' and 10 xml documents as well in search app directory?

2) Since I'm redirecting after post to the 'results' views, so, How do I mention about it in the urls.py i.e. in "urlpatterns" .

3) Then do I need to mention the "context" in the "def front_page(request):" ?will this definition of views work fine without it because according to me , it is not necessary that we have to use context in every def of views.

Django is new to me and I don't have any hands on experience of it.So,

Please help.

Comment: please anyone help me at this......

Answer (score 1):

1. keep 'skey' in the same app directory. keep xml documents under app directory is not good but acceptable idea, better choice is put them under some place like `"/var/www/your-site/xml-data"` / `"d:/your-site/xml-docs/"` and access them via absolute path
2. see following code

   ```
   from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url    
   from django.contrib import admin
   admin.autodiscover()    
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^search/$','search.views.front_page'),
       url(r'^results/$','search.views.results'),
       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   )
   ```
3. the normal use is like this: (the get_template and render will automatically called)

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import render_to_response as rr

   def home(req):   
       # do some work here
       return rr('your template file',
           { ... }, # your parameters
           context_instance = RequestContext(req))
   ```

Comment: for the 2nd point , just look into the code where it is written : "return HttpResponseRedirect('/results/')", this is the part that I'm talking about . Since I'm redirecting to view result , how do I mention it in the urls.py file which is the part of any project. Can you tell me now?

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA still no idea what you are talking, you do not need metion about redirecting in urls.py, just config '/results/' with a controller in urls.py, it will automatically find that controller, and return that action's response

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA I've update my post, the redirect is consider like a url, so you need config like what I post. and you are not allowed to have two <r'^search/$'> with same pattern, only the last will work.